# What is cardinality() in presto sql?

Tags: sql, presto

Does anyone know the purpose of cardinality() function in sql? How does it work with unnest function?

```
SELECT story_id, 
    cardinality(image_tags) AS image_tags, 
    cardinality(comment_tags) as comment_tags
    from 
    story_tab
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(data.images) t (url, item_tags, comment_tags)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cardinality()` -- as explained in the [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) -- returns the size of an array.

In this case, `image_tags` and `comment_tags` are array columns in `data.images`.  This is counting the size of those arrays for each url.

I should note that `data.images` is, itself, an array, so each image has these tags.

So, this is returning the number of image tags and the number of comment tags for each image in `data`.  I would recommend including information about the image too -- or aggregating by the story.